# Transpose dataframe from wide-to-long with multiple values

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, wide-format-data

I have wide data with multiple values that I need to transpose into a long data table. I've looked at several sites and StackOverflow and cannot seem to find the answer to this, even though its so simple.

Some example data:

```
#example data
wide <- data.frame(
  VariableName = c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5"),
 Year1 = c(411,723,325,456,579),
 Year2 = c(123,300,400,500,600),
 Year3 = c(1457,1000,569,896,956)
)
```

which looks like this

```
  VariableName Year1 Year2 Year3
1         Var1   411   123  1457
2         Var2   723   300  1000
3         Var3   325   400   569
4         Var4   456   500   896
5         Var5   579   600   956
```

And I need it to look like this

```
VariableName    Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
Year1           411   723   325   456   579
Year2           123   300   400   500   600
Year3           1457  1000  569   896   956
```

I've tried several functions, including gather(), pivot_longer(), melt() but I just can't seem to get the function to either work, or give me the results I need.

Comment: We need to reshape twice, wide-to-long, then long-to-wide.

Comment: Thank you! Definitely required me to rethink it. I'm a native SAS user.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** With `tidyr`, `pivot_longer` and then `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)

wide %>%
  pivot_longer(-VariableName, names_to = 'Year') %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Year, names_from = VariableName)
```

**Option 2:** You can also use some useful tools provided by `tibble` to operate row names before and after transposing the data.

```r
library(tibble)

wide %>%
  column_to_rownames("VariableName") %>%
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Year")
```

###### Output

```
# # A tibble: 3 × 6
#   Year   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Year1   411   723   325   456   579
# 2 Year2   123   300   400   500   600
# 3 Year3  1457  1000   569   896   956
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are only looking for a transposed version of your data frame, you can simply transpose it with `t()`. Directly applying `t()` to your data frame does not work, though, because you have stored the row names in a column, which means that data coercion will cast all your data to the least common denominator, i.e. to strings:

```
> t(wide)
             [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
VariableName "Var1" "Var2" "Var3" "Var4" "Var5"
Year1        "411"  "723"  "325"  "456"  "579" 
Year2        "123"  "300"  "400"  "500"  "600" 
Year3        "1457" "1000" " 569" " 896" " 956"
```

Solution: Store the variable names in the row names, not in a column.

```
> row.names(wide) <- wide$VariableName
> wide <- subset(wide, select=-c(VariableName))
> t(wide)
       Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
Year1  411  723  325  456  579
Year2  123  300  400  500  600
Year3 1457 1000  569  896  956
```

As @darren-tsai pointed out, the result of `t()` is a matrix, so if you need a data frame, you must convert it with `as.data.frame`.